# Uncheck item when it is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-4.4-kitkat, checkedtextview

I have a `ListActivty` with listview choice mode set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` The item layout contains only a `CheckedTextView`. By default when the activity is shown all items are unchecked. If the user clicks on an item it is automatically getting checked and check-mark is shown. Clicking another item unchecks the previous item. All this is working out of the box.

What I want to do is to uncheck an item of the user clicks on an already checked item. I have overridden `onListItemClick` method to detect if the item is already checked and uncheck it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view;
    if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
        listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that on Android 4.4 `checkedTextView.isChecked()` always returns true: if I click on an unchecked item it returns true and clicking on checked item returns true as well. I have tried `listview.isItemChecked(position)` but it works the same way.

Is there any other way to detect that I have clicked on a checked item so that I can uncheck it?

Comment: Not an _answer drawing from credible and/or official sources,_ but you could add a variable to track currently selected item and override it's checked state independently from `checkedTextView.isChecked()`.

Comment: @giorgi if you are using custom adapter than first change particular position's object and than use this ItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I think you have to set tag when particular list item is checked or unchecked so when you try to check is checked at time get this value from item tag.

Comment: isChecked returns mChecked. Why do you think it does return alway `true`? [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java#CheckedTextView.isChecked%28%29) some reference

Comment: Do you want to check and uncheck on list row click or on checkbox click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KitKat `AbsListView` is notifying the listener after handling the click, thus it is already checked when you call `checkedTextView.isChecked()` in your listener.

Try creating your custom ListView which overrides `performItemClick()`, save the item state before the super call and act upon it aftewards like this (untested):

```
@Override
public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
    boolean checkedBeforeClick = isItemChecked(position);
    super.performItemClick(view, position, id);
    if (checkedBeforeClick) {
        setItemChecked(position, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably work but why should I jump through hoops to have such a simple feature work.

Comment: @Giorgi: if you call this jumping through hoops then you must be new to Android. No offense meant ;-).

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: Yes, Android is full of such "features" but I think this is simple enough feature to have working without hoops

Answer (score 2):

To check or uncheck the item on checkbox click, you can set listener on CheckBox inside adapter. Inside onCheckedChangeListener you can do your stuff.

If you want to check and uncheck the item on list row click, you can set onitemclicklistener on the list and inside onitemclick you can write this:

```
String isChecked = fullItemList.get(position).getIsChecked();
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
    if(isChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        fullItemList.get(position).setIsChecked("false");
        checkbox.setChecked(false);

    } else {
        fullItemList.get(position).setIsChecked("true");
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
        checkedItemList.add(fullItemList.get(position));
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't an "elegant" solution for this...

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    private int itemSelectedIndex;

    /**
     * Initializer "proxy".
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return
     */
    public OnItemClickListener init(int index) {
        itemSelectedIndex = index;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (itemSelectedIndex != position) {
            itemSelectedIndex = position;
            getArguments().putInt(ListView.class.getName(), position);
        } else {
            itemSelectedIndex = -1;
            listTravelBags.setItemChecked(position, false);
            getArguments().putInt(ListView.class.getName(), -1);
        }
    }
}.init(getArguments().getInt(ListView.class.getName(), -1) /* get last checked item after config changes/restarts, etc. */));
```

Note: `getArguments()`is a method inside a Fragment. If you want to use an Activity (or in your case a ListActivity), use SharedPreferences or your savestate Bundle.